# Modify FlipClock so that timer doesn't reset when you refresh the page

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I am currently using FlipClock.js to create a countdown timer.  However, I noticed that when I refresh the page, the countdown timer resets.  I would like to prevent this from happening.

My current code is here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="clock"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>

      <script>
        var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(2, {
          countdown: true,
          minimumDigits: 2,
            callbacks: {
            stop:function() {
              $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!');
            }
          }
        });
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a link to a JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/40re721m/2

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set own time then calculate differently from current time then set differently in FlipClock countdown

```js
var date = new Date(2020, 0, 23);
var now = new Date();
var diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000);

var clock = new FlipClock($('.your-clock'), diff, {
 countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $(".your-message").append("finished");
    },
  }
});

clock();
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
      <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="your-clock"></div>
  <div class="your-message">
   
    </div>
    

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes sense.  But let's say I want to set the timer for some specific time (e.g. 15 seconds in the future).  How would I do this?  I tried something like 
```var date = new Date();
date.setSeconds( date.getSeconds() + 15 );```, but this clearly won't work because 15 seconds is added every time you refresh the page.